# URI Encoding issue for Characters like Pound symbol (£ or ₤)

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, character-encoding

I am facing issue while trying into insert special symbols like pound character (£ or ₤ ) in DB. These are getting displayed as ?? in the front end

We use tomcat as app server and have below configration in that

```
URIEncoding="UTF-8"
```

Before inserting the text to DB we are performing the below check

```
String Text = new String(request.getParameter("Text").getBytes("8859_1"),"UTF-8");
```

I dont have much idea about what the above code does

But when i remove `"URIEncoding="UTF-8"`  from tomcat server.xml,these characters are loading fine

According to  http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Configuring+Tomcat%27s+URI+encoding by default tomcat uses `"ISO-8859-1"` encoding

can anyone help on this please?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Unless you are having problems with GET parameters, the URIEncoding setting it not relevant to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking Tomcat to give you values formatted as UTF-8, then converting that to a byte array based on ISO-8859-1 character set code points. You're then directly casting those values back to UTF-8 code points, which is resulting in the characters getting garbled.

Just remove the conversion stuff, leave the `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` entry in your config, and it should work fine.

Also, keep in mind that your output encoding is important. If you're sending back UTF-8 encoded pages, but have the encoding set differently in the page's meta tags or the `Content-Encoding` HTTP response header, you'll get garbled results for certain characters.

Comment: Eliminated the rolling debug session, this isn't what Stack Overflow is for.